# How to have a sql_variant parameter for a SQL CLR stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

How can one add a sql_variant parameter to a SQL CLR stored procedure?  Using System.Object does not work, and I don't see any attributes that I can use.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void ClearOnePartition(
    SqlString aString
    , /* I want this to be a sql_variant */ object aVariant
)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can. All I can find is lots of references to how different client APIs translate them into e.g. nvarchar or binary columns. Does it have to be an sql_variant?

Comment: @Damied_The_Unbeliever: yes, it does need to be a sql_variant.  I am trying to pass in the value of a boundary for any given partition, which exists in SQL as a sql_variant type.

Comment: Boundary values for partitions aren't, strictly sql_variants (they can't, for instance, accept a value of type text). I don't think they actually have a well defined type in SQL. Looking in the SMO functions for working with partition functions, they're treated as Object, so I don't believe there's a better .NET type for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28SQL.100%29.aspx) from SQL Books Online, [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) is listed as the correct type to use to map [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx).

I created a simple SQL Server project and added the following class to it:

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void StoredProcedure1(object param1)
    {
        // Put your code here
        //Trace.Write(param1);
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(param1.ToString());

    }
};
```

I then modified the test.sql file to exercise this stored proc:

```
DECLARE @thing sql_variant = 'hahahahaha';

EXEC dbo.StoredProcedure1 @thing
```

This runs as expected and produces the following output:

> hahahahaha
>
> No rows affected.
>
> (0 row(s)  returned)
>
> Finished running sp_executesql.

Answer (score 2):

Partition Boundary values, as shown in the [CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx) documentation, can be one of many different types:

> All data types are valid for use as partitioning columns, except text, ntext, image, xml, timestamp, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), alias data types, or CLR user-defined data types.

And their actual datatype is stored in [sys.partition_parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175054.aspx).

But if one is selecting them out of [sys.partition_range_values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187780.aspx), then the `value` field is of type `SQL_VARIANT` (and for good reason, obviously).

Yes, `SQL_VARIANT` (as already stated) maps to `object` in .NET.

If you need to check for NULLs, compare the object to `DBNull.Value`.

If you want to know the underlying type of the value in the object (it most likely isn't going to be `SQL_VARIANT` / `object` ), use the `GetType()` method:

```cs
if (aVariant.GetType() == typeof(SqlInt16))
```