# CLR sproc, object-parameter accepting nvarchar(max)

Tags: t-sql, sqlclr, clrstoredprocedure

I have a CLR stored procedure that takes a value from an arbitrary column as parameter. To handle all possible columns the parameter if of type [object / sql_variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382113/how-to-have-a-sql-variant-parameter-for-a-sql-clr-stored-procedure):

```
[SqlFunction]  
public static bool IsTrue(object storedValue...
```

When passing in data from a column of type `nvarchar(max)` I get:

> "Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is
>   incompatible with sql_variant".

If the parameter had been a string I could have declared it as `SqlChar` or decorated it with `[SqlFacet(MaxSize=-1)]` to make it accept columns with length > 4000. How is it done for objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can achieve what you are attempting.  The upper boundary on sql_variant is [8k bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx).  nvarchar(max) is *capped* at [2^31-1 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)  SQL Server is detecting you are, potentially, attempting to stuff the state of Texas into a Dixie cup.  Due to the 8k sql_variant limit, no decorator exists that will convince SQL Server to let you do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That makes sense. I did a workaround in this case and now know I must try something else in the first place the next time.